# How to display value instead of percentage in pie chart in Kibana?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, pie-chart

I'm trying to setup a kibana pie-chart visualization. By default it shows the relative percentages of the terms (=slices). Is there a way to display only the absolute values (e.g. document counts) instead of the percentages?

I'm using Kibana version 7.1.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this is not possible as of today.

Looking at this [discussion](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/how-can-i-display-count-instead-of-percentage-in-pie/150992) it was not possible in October of 2018.
There is an [issue on github](https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/34050) that addresses exactly your need, **but it is still open.**

However you can still see the absolute value by enabling the options displayed in the following picture and then hovering over the slices:

[image]

As an alternative you could setup a simple data table to display the absolute values like so:

[image]

Hope this helps.